# Is the diagonalizing matrix for a matrix with non-repeated eigenvalues unique?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

In presence of degeneracy in the eigenvalues, the diagonalizing matrix is not unique. Is the converse also true? Suppose $A$ is an arbitrary (say, $3\times 3$) matrix with non-degenerate eigenvalues $a, b$ and $c$. Is the diagonalizing matrix unique? If not, a counterexample will answer my question. If yes, I would prefer a proof.

**Note** When I say unique, I mean apart from reshuffling of normalized eigenvectors among the columns.

Comment: No, its not. It depends how you set up the matrix $D$, that is, the order in which you put the eigenvalues on the main diagonal. Also remember that any multiple of an eigenvector is also an eigenvector. (Eigenvectors are not unique)

Comment: @imranfat Please have a look at the note I've added.

Answer (score 1):

It is never unique. If $P$ is such that$$P^{-1}.A.P=\begin{pmatrix}a&0&0\\0&b&0\\0&0&c\end{pmatrix}$$then, if you replace each column of $P$ by itself times a non-zero scalar, then the new matrix will work too.

Comment: (+1) or more simply a multiple of the identity, true.

Comment: Please have a look at the note I've added.

Comment: @mithusengupta123 With that note, the question became another question. But you can still replace each eigenvector by its symmetric.

Comment: "_But you can still replace each eigenvector by its symmetric._" What does that mean?

Comment: @mithusengupta123 It means that you can replace any column of $P$ by its symmetric. The new matrix will work too.